# I'm receiving NoMethodError on Assert, Ruby 1.9.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, assert

I'm new to Ruby, and running this test:

> ```
> require 'selenium-webdriver' 
> require 'capybara' 
> require 'capybara/cucumber' 
> require 'rspec/expectations' 
> require 'test/unit'
>
>
> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox 
>  Capybara.default_driver = :selenium
>
>  Given /^I am on the homepage$/ do
>  driver.navigate.to "http://testurl:8080/" 
>  end
>
> When(/^I enter admin authentication$/) do 
> usrname = > driver.find_element(:name, 'username') 
> usrname.send_keys "admin" 
> puts "Username Entered" 
> passwd = driver.find_element(:name, 'password')
> passwd.send_keys "admin" 
> puts "Password Entered" 
> passwd.submit 
> puts "Details Submitted" 
> end
>
> Then(/^I should be on the homepage$/) do
>  sleep 5 
> displayName = driver.find_element(:id, 'prefs_menu') 
> assert displayName.text == "Administrator" #
> puts "Correct User Display Name" 
> end
> ```

And I keep getting the error

```
 undefined method `assert' for #<Object:0x2895258> (NoMethodError) ./features/login_steps.rb:42:in `/^I should be on the homepage$/' features\login.feature:10:in `Then I should be on the homepage'
```

Its probably something I'm overlooking completely - but any help?

Comment: Is this a typo `usrname = > driver.find_element(:name, 'username')`? I am sure it should be `usrname = driver.find_element(:name, 'username')`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
assert(displayName.text == "Administrator")
```

Comment: No, unfortunately I'm still getting the same error. I'm also getting it if I attempt assert_equals - am I missing a gem?